# what's the reason of my code? a unhandled exception

Tags: c++, pointers, unhandled-exception

debug src: http://www.cppblog.com/Files/mymsdn/cvector-bug-vs2008-201007101651.zip

> Hey all, I have repair my code, thanks yours help! You can download the correct version of my code.

src: http://www.cppblog.com/Files/mymsdn/cvector-vs2008-20100710.rar

I am trying to write a C language version of vector. I use the `void ** a` the pRoot indicate the pointer vector. I want to keep the void ** p available, than I malloc a memory.

like this :`cvector_ptr_ptr = &cvector_ptr;`

I pass the `cvector_ptr_ptr` to each function to deal with it.

In my code, I encounter a unhandled exception. I think I have read overrun. But in the function `"insert"`, I can use `(*cvector_ptr_ptr)->element_size` to get the size value. I pass the `cvector_ptr_ptr` to the function `"insert_copy"` I can't use the same code `[(*cvector_ptr_ptr)->element_size]` to get the value.

What's wrong with me?

Comment: post your actual code...

Comment: Post the relevant source here. And decide whether this is C or C++.

Comment: Can you provide error description?

Comment: *What's the reason of my code?* - That's one for philosophyoverflow.com.

Comment: Why don't you simply wrap the C++ std::vector in a C interface?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your "create_vector_n" function, there:

```
cvector_ptr_ptr = &cvector_ptr;
return cvector_ptr_ptr;
```

You are returning a pointer to a stack variable (cvector_ptr), which is terribly wrong.

Comment: I think it copy the value of cvector_ptr_ptr to the result (out of scope), but the *cvector_ptr_ptr is also available, because it's created from malloc. 

And the function "insert" is available

Comment: No, it really returns an address somewhere into a stack. However - it may actually work for a while! At least until that stack value is overwritten by another function call for example.

Comment: it may actually work for a while! ———————————— is it the right reason of why function insert is ok and the function insert_copy encounter a crash? What's the best practice of this pattern? I move the variable into the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has many problems, one problem that is really evident is

```
offset = ((*cvector_ptr_ptr)->count + 1) * element_size;
                                    ^^^
                            this is the problem
```

The first element you add should be written to offset zero, not `element_size`.

Comment: The code haven't setp into this line.......get the unhandled exception before....